# What does "asp.net" mean?

Tags: asp.net

I know asp stands for Active Server Pages but wondering if "Active Server" means anything actually?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ASP.NET pages aren't *static*; they have executable, server-side code behind them that may dynamically generate page content or interact with the serving system—they're *active* (web) server pages.

Answer (score 5):

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972347.aspx), it refers to the ActiveX components.

> Microsoft® Active Server Pages (ASP) is the server-side execution environment in Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) 3.0 that enables you to run ActiveX™ scripts and ActiveX server components on the server. By combining scripts and components, developers can create dynamic content and powerful Web-based applications easily.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, ASP.NET isn't *really* an upgrade for ASP, it was just named that way to get it past corporate departments - you could sell it to your higher-ups as an "upgrade" to ASP even though it was pretty much a separate technology.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have used "Active" in the past for a few products, eg; Active Directory.
Many other technologies that mix presentation and logic have also used X S)erver P)ages - eg: J)ava S)erver P)ages.